# Pausing a thread that implements Runnable once surfaceDestroyed is called

Tags: java, android

I have a thread class called GameLoopThread that implements Runnable. I also have a class called GameView that extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder.Callback. When I call surfaceDestroyed in the GameView class, I want to pause the thread. When GameLoopThread was extending Thread instead of implementing Runnable, I called gameLoopThread.join().

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);

    while (retry) {
        try {
            gameLoopThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

However, now that I am implementing Runnable in GameLoopThread as most people say it is better practice, I need an alternative to calling join(). How would I go about editing the surfaceDestroyed method?

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);

    while (retry) {
        try {
            //Edit this line
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `When I call surfaceDestroyed in the GameView class` -- the app framework will call `surfaceDestroyed()`; don't call it yourself.  Why isn't `join()` working for you?  You can find some information about managing the interaction between the Activity and Surface lifecycles in https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity

Comment: join() is a part of the Thread class, but it isn't in the Runnable interface. Do you just leave surfaceDestroyed() blank then?

Comment: You need to start the thread somewhere, with something like (quoting the java docs), `new Thread(p).start();`.  You join that thread object.  If you are following approach #2 from the architecture doc, you do want to join that thread in `surfaceDestroyed()`.  For example, https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/HardwareScalerActivity.java